# Capture errors in python cronjobs

Tags: cron, python

I have a python script as a cron job that is called like this

```
/path/to/python /path/to/myscript myparam
```

When an error occurs in the script, the cronjob silently fails. When I run the same command from the command line, I get a stack trace. How can I bring my script to output the stack trace (or write it to a file) when running as a cron job? I have already set the `MAILTO` variable. I have also tried putting

```
/path/to/python /path/to/myscript myparam 2>&1 >> /path/to/logfile
```

in the crontab but logfile remains empty.

**Update:** The call without output redirection works now. It was not an issue with the python script, but a wrong separator in the MAILTO crontab setting. Remember: Use commas and don't put spaces after the commas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the wrong order.

- `2>&1` means that redirect standard error to the standard output and
  both to the terminal
- `>> /path/to/logfile` redirects standard output to the log file. You
  didn't mentioned the standard error, so it still go to the terminal.

Try this:

```
/path/to/python /path/to/myscript myparam >> /path/to/logfile 2>&1
```

Make sure that the user who run this script has write permission to the log file.